# Sharing the same viewmodel between pages/main page and sub-page

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I'm kinda new to the whole windows platform and I'm trying to create mvvm portable class library for windows and windows phone. Now that I have all my smaller pieces ready, I've found myself stuck at trying to figure out how to achieve the following with mvvm.

I have a main page where I can see the information for a car rental reservation and in this page. I'll be able to see a pickup location and a dropoff location (which are both inside a PointOfInterestViewModel). When I click on either the pickup/dropoff location. I want to switch to anther page which has a pivot with multiple list of possible locations. Once the user selects a location, I'll want to update the location in the PointOfInterestViewModel and then send the user back to the main view.

Is there a way where I can achieve it without having multiple PointOfInterestViewModel(s) and passing data between them? I would much rather have one single viewmodel but still adhere to mvvm.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the PointOfInterestViewModel on the App class, bind the main form to it - then you could update it from the pivot:

((App)App.Current).PointOfInterestVM = ....

Comment: Isn't having something in the App class considered bad practice for mvvm? (not completely sure).

Comment: Possibly. From your description above this seems like an application setting, which made me think of putting it on the application class. Another option would be to have the Main form pass a reference to its PointOfInterestViewModel to the pivot form.

Comment: Hm, the second option sounds like a compelling one. How would I go around passing that for a windows phone app?

Comment: You could pass it in the constructor of the pivot view